# ClassName.this in extended classes

Tags: java, inheritance, scope

I've inherited some code, and I'm trying to refactor it in an attempt to clean it up.

This is a simplified case of how I received the code:

```
public class Foo
{
   private void doSomething()
   {
       someOtherAction(Foo.this);
   }
   protected class FooChildClass
   {
        protected void anotherAction()
        {
             createDialogBox(Foo.this);
        }
   }
}
//totally not related to class Foo even though most code is duplicated
public class Bar
{
   private void doSomething()
   {
       someOtherAction(Bar.this);
   }
   protected class BarChildClass
   {
        protected void anotherAction()
        {
             createDialogBox(Bar.this);
        }
   }
}
```

Now, here's the catch - after further examination of the code, *Bar* is almost a carbon-copy of *Foo* with some slight changes here and there.

I'd like to condense my code into something like this:

```
//superclass
public class Foo
{
   protected void doSomething()
   {
       someOtherAction(Foo.this);
   }
   protected class ChildClass
   {
        protected void anotherAction()
        {
             createDialogBox(Foo.this);
        }
   }
}
//inherits from Foo and only overrides when necessary
public class Bar extends Foo
{
   //rely on base implementation of doSomething
   //override other functions only when necessary
}
```

Will my condensed code run successfully? I have a C# background, so I understand a good bit of Java syntax, but C# doesn't have anything similar to *ClassName.this*.

I'm figuring that *ClassName.this* is meant to resolve scoping issues by defining what 'this' is intended - and that with my modified code, *Bar* is indeed a *Foo* object too -  but I figure I would ask to be sure!

Edited original question for clarification

Comment: It looks like you're omitting something here. Is this `doSomething` in an inner class? Looks this way, otherwise `Bar.this` doesn't make too much sense. And do `Bar` and `Foo` implement an interface`, preferrably a common one that's the argument for `someOtherAction`?

Comment: There are no interfaces, but there are some inner classes. Both Foo and Bar implement delegates, so from what I can tell, any code that uses 'Foo.this' and 'Bar.this' are passing context or a delegate elsewhere as a parameter.

Comment: Updated question to provide more clarity

Comment: What does `createDialogBox()` do with `Foo` and `Bar`, respectively? It's probably possible to extract a common interface.

Comment: No idea, actually. The code I received is poorly documented and has gone through no QA testing; I was assigned to fix a bug in the Foo class, noticed that the code is pretty much cloned for Bar (which also has the bug in it), and figured that if I’m going to fix something, might as well fix it correctly.

Comment: From what i can tell, it calls a static helper class that generates an alert prompt.

Comment: @JeffreyKern I updated my answer according to your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Foo.this` is equivalent to `this`. Therefore your condensed code is Okay with no requirement of being changed.

The following test code is to test your updated program:

```
    Foo f = new Foo();
    Foo.ChildClass fc = f.new ChildClass();
    f.doSomething();
    fc.anotherAction();

    Bar b = new Bar();
    Bar.ChildClass bc = b.new ChildClass();
    b.doSomething();
    bc.anotherAction();
```

The output is:

```
Foo@52e922
Foo@52e922
Bar@25154f
Bar@25154f
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that, `doSomething` and `anotherAction` have been changed to print out `Foo.this` to see which object it references.

Answer (score 3):

Referring to your most recent edit I composed the following example:

```
public class Foo {
    public void printMe() {
        System.out.println("I'm foo");
    }

    public class Child {
        public void printMe() {
            Foo.this.printMe();
        }
    }
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    public void printMe() {
        System.out.println("I'm bar");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Bar().new Child().printMe();
    }
}
```

The result was:

```
I'm bar
```

Which concludes, that `Foo.this.printMe()` does **not** statically refer to the outer class `Foo`, but to the outer **instance** of the `Child` instance, which in this case is an instance of `Bar`.

---

### For further reading:

The `Classname.this` syntax is used for inner classes.

You can use the following example to try a bit around and see its effects:

```
public class Foo {
    private int value = 1;

    public class Bar {
        private int value = 2;

        public void printValue() {
            System.out.println(Foo.this.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding derivation, there's no way to explicitly refer to a certain super type in java, like in C. However, you can refer to your super class using the `super` keyword.

With java 1.8 and default interface methods, the `Classname.super` syntax was introduced:

```
public interface Foo {
    default int getValue() {
        return 1;
    }
}

public interface Bar {
    default int getValue() {
        return 2;
    }
}

public class Impl implements Foo, Bar {
    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return Bar.super.getValue();
    }
}
```

However, you can still only refer to direct super types. Everything other will be denied by the compiler.